# Copy data files from internal stage table to Logical tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am dealing with json and csv files moving from Unix/S3 bucket to Internal/External stage receptively
and I don't have any issue with json files copy from Internal/External stages to Static or logical table, where I am storing as JsonFileName, and JsonFileContent

Trying to copy to Static table ( parse_json($1) is working for JSON)

```
COPY INTO LogicalTable (FILE_NM, JSON_CONTENT) 
from (
  select METADATA$FILENAME AS FILE_NM, parse_json($1) AS JSON_CONTENT 
  from @$TSJsonExtStgName
) 
file_format = (type='JSON' strip_outer_array = true);
```

I am looking for something similar for CSV,  copy csv file name and csv file content from internal/external staging to Static or logical tables. Mainly looking for this to separate file copy and file loading, load may fail due number of columns mismatch, newline character, or bad data in one of the records.

If any one of below gets clarified is fine, please suggest

1)    Trying to copy to Static table (METADATA$?????? not working for CSV)

```
select METADATA$FILENAME AS FILE_NM, METADATA$?????? AS CSV_CONTENT 
from @INT_REF_CSV_UNIX_STG
```

2)    Trying for dynamic columns (T.* not working for CSV)

```
SELECT METADATA$FILENAME,$1, $2, $3, T.* 
FROM @INT_REF_CSV_UNIX_STG(FILE_FORMAT => CSV_STG_FILE_FORMAT)T
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether the file is CSV or JSON, you need to make sure that your SELECT matches the table layout of the target table.  I assume with your JSON, your target table is 2 columns...filename and a VARIANT column for your JSON contents.  For CSV, you need to do the same thing.  So, you need to do the $1, $2, etc. for each column that you want from the file...that matches your target table.

I have no idea what you are referencing with METADATA$??????, btw.

---ADDED

Based on your comment below, you have 2 options, which aren't native to a COPY INTO statement:

1) Create a Stored Procedure that looks at a table DDL and generates a COPY INTO statement that has the static columns defined and then executing the COPY INTO from within the SP.

2) Leverage an External Table.  By defining an External Table with the METADATA$FILENAME and the rest of the columns, the External Table will return the CSV contents to you as JSON.  From there, you can treat it in the same way you are treating your JSON tables.

Comment: I've added some more options to the answer above based on your comments.

Comment: Thanks Mike, you are right, we have two column in json Stage table 
I will store the file name in first, next I will store the entire json content in variant column.

But in csv, I am forced to match the column list between csv file vs target table, but I am looking to do it dynamically. 

Wants to store all different metadata csv files (difference column list ) to store in one stage table and copy respective file pattern to load into respective table.

"METADATA$FILENAME" we have this to get the filename respectively do we have any similar keyword to get the Content of CSV as varient

Comment: Based upon your comments my understanding is, we can't able to get the CSV content as variant column in stage table, also we don't have any inbuilt key words to it e.g. metadata$.
Unfortunately I have to do extract and load from Unix cmd (snowsql) can't do it in StroredProc also External tables is not my primary stage to accomplish this., but based upon your option 1,  I am managed to generate the dynamic column mapping using information_schema.columns to load different csvs

Comment: Sounds like that is your best option, yes.